# Big transition delay between the scheduled state and enqueued state in Jobrunr

Tags: java, scheduler, jobrunr

I am using Jobrunr 6.1.0 with Redis as storage provider.
Jobrunr is working great but there is a big delay between the job scheduled time and the job enqueued time when is retrying a job. It could be several hours. For example, from the dashboard:

```
Job scheduled - Retry 1 of 5 - Wed Jun 14 2023 22:55:12 GMT+0200
Job enqueued                 - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:03:15 GMT+0200
Processing Job               - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:03:25 GMT+0200
Job processing failed        - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:00:25 GMT+0200

Job scheduled - Retry 2 of 5 - Wed Jun 14 2023 00:04:01 GMT+0200
Job enqueued                 - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:45:08 GMT+0200
Processing Job               - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:45:11 GMT+0200
Job processing failed        - Thu Jun 15 2023 00:45:12 GMT+0200
```

The number of jobs per day is not high, 1000 per day.
My custom properties are:

```
numberOfRetries = 5
backOffPolicyTimeSeed = 6
dashboardEnabled = true
dashboardPort = 8000
backgroundJobServerEnabled = true
backgroundJobServerPollIntervalInSeconds = 75
backgroundJobServerDeleteSucceededJobsAfterInHours = 24
backgroundJobServerPermanentlyDeleteDeletedJobsAfterInHours = 1
```

I can understand a delay in the queue because there are not workers available, but what are the possible reasons for this transition delay between the scheduled state and the enqueued state?

Comment: How many recurring jobs do you have?

Comment: There are no recurring jobs, only jobs that are retried when they fail. In 3 months were processed 1902 jobs,  392 with 5 tries.

Comment: JobRunr 6.0 and 6.1 have a bug that may be related (see also the website). Can you try upgrading?

Comment: I read the bug, but it's not related, the jobs are getting stuck in the scheduled state. Actually, the transition between enqueued and processing is fairly fast. What is the condition to move from scheduled to enqueued?

Comment: Well, I don't agree completely that it is unrelated... that's why I advise you to upgrade . Once you are on the latest version and it still happens, feel free to open an issue.